# Why doesn't Postman post this request?

Tags: javascript, mongoose, schema, postman

I do not understand why Postman cannot post the raw body data I am giving it. 
Here is my header:
[Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvMCA.png)
My input:
[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olgm6.png)
The error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lq9xU.png)
The error suggests something is wrong with my backend, but when I npm start it, it runs with no problems. I do not know what the problem is.
My file directory is this:

```
auth
|
node_modules
public
views
routes -- auth.js
model -- User.js
.env
index.js
package.json
package-lock.json
```

auth.js:

```js
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require('../model/User');

router.post('/register',async(req,res)=>{
    const user = new User({
        name:req.body.name,
        email:req.body.email,
        password:req.body.password
    });
    try{
        const savedUser = await user.save();
        res.send(savedUser);
    }catch(err){
        res.status(400).send(err);
    };
});

module.exports = router;
```

User.js:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        max:300,
        min:6
    },
    email:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        max:255,
        min:6
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        max:1024,
        min:6
    },
    date:{
        type:Date,
        default:Date.now
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User',userSchema);
```

Here is the full project on plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/ydQwisGd3kVC06RqvhjR?p=catalogue
A file that has a "/" in it means "folder/file", otherwise its in the root.

Comment: Just to verify, is your server running when you're making that request through postman?

Comment: Yes @Robert Perez

Comment: Another question, does your personal .env file have the correct DB info? I see in plunker it has <username><password> (which is fine for plunker so others wont see your personal info) but if its the same in your environment you'll get that problem..

Comment: What's the HTTP status code you are getting when running via Postman? If it's not `404` you should be able to check logs at the server end to see what's going wrong.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late responses. Yes, in my .env I only added <username><password> because this is a public post, but in my actual project its correct @Robert Perez

Comment: The HTTP status is 400 @xk0der

Comment: In your .env file can you remove the  quotation marks? So it reads: DB_CONNECT = mongodb+srv://<username><password>@cluster0-wu2im.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority;

Comment: I tried that, and I got this error: https://i.imgur.com/jq3aMxG.png @Robert Perez

Comment: And this message in my terminal: https://i.imgur.com/E4XKl0O.png @Robert Perez

Comment: `HTTP 400` indicates `Bad request`! That indicates the request you are sending to your server is malformed. This may occur due to various reasons. Using the wrong HTTP Method (using GET instead of POST), incorrect/missing query parameters, incorrect body payload, incorrect/missing headers. You should access errors in your server to understand what is missing.